# Interpreting stored cloud file from PointCloud2 data type

Tags: pcl, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having a problem in interpreting a point cloud data stored in PointCloud2 of data type. The file is generated by "rostopic echo.." my cloud topic. My goal is to find corresponding x, y and z values, in terms of coordinates so that I can use them in plotting with MatLab or Octave. I am aware of this [link](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/basic_structures.php#basic-structures), but, I still cannot see the use of it.

The fields in the stored file looks like this:

```
%time,field.header.seq,field.header.stamp,field.header.frame_id,field.height,field.width,field.fields0.name,field.fields0.offset,field.fields0.datatype,field.fields0.count,field.fields1.name,field.fields1.offset "and so on"
```

Or, is it wise to convert from PointCloud2 first into another format before I can plot it. If so, in what format, it serves the best for this purpose? Or any other smarter way of doing it.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12834/interpreting-stored-cloud-file-from-pointcloud2-data-type/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is probably a more direct method, but I've used PCL's `.pcd` format to accomplish this.

**EDIT:** Dan Lazewatsky pointed out pointcloud_to_pcd, which converts a ROS `PointCloud2` msg to a `.pcd` file. See his comment for the docs.

Once you have it as a `.pcd`, it should be fairly easy to parse. After the header the points are listed one per line: `x y z rgb`. Note that PCL packs the RBG (and alpha, if you're using it) channels into a single float.

Related docs and tutorials: [pcl::fromROSmsg](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.5.1/namespacepcl.html#a2829cb35031f3c5ad0403de70f779915) | [writing to a `.pcd` file](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/writing_pcd.php#writing-pcd) | [`.pcd` file format](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcd_file_format.php#pcd-file-format)

---

Originally posted by [tbernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1746/tbernhard/) with karma: 80 on 2012-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-07-11**:
pointcloud_to_pcd in pcl_ros does exactly that: http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros#pointcloud_to_pcd

**Comment by [tbernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1746/tbernhard/) on 2012-07-11**:
Thanks, hadn't come across that.  good to know

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I had a similar problem, maybe this answer can be useful for you [this link](http://answers.ros.org/question/209578/doubt-about-interpreting-pointcloud2-data/)

---

Originally posted by [Wilianson](https://answers.ros.org/users/18601/wilianson/) with karma: 21 on 2016-06-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1